# mysqli_real_string_escape failing with GET

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a static database connection established in a file which I include as

```
include_once 'database.inc.php';
```

named `$mysqli`.

When I pass a parameter `$tbname` from a form using `$tbname = $_GET['tbname']`, and attempt to use `$tbname = $mysqli->real_esacpe_string($tbname)`, it produces identical output to $tbname, including when invalid characters such as `/,'"` are used in the name.

Based on looking at other questions and proper usage, I cannot find a reason why the string escape should fail. It also fails if a procedural call is used to `mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $tbname)`.

When `$tbname` is valid and not string escaped by the function, my query

```
query = $mysqli->prepare("CREATE TABLE $tbname (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)") or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$query]");
```

works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no reason to use this function for escaping a table name, and you should never use it for such a purpose.
2. There is no reason in creating tables from user input, and you should never create tables on the fly, but always have solid and predefined database structure.
3. mysqli_real_escape_string DOES escape these symbols `\'"`. But you should never use it. Instead, you have to use prepared statements

Comment: Well the reason why I wasn't using prepared statements was because apparently you cannot dynamically create tables like such. Thank you for your answer.